# Как назваются такие поля?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Сейчас обучаюсь верстке, подскажите пожалуйста как называются такие поля? При клике они открываются, появляется текст

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ```accordion```

Comment: @soledar10 Благодарю